# Want to display current RSI value in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Unable to display RSI value on chart or in table format. Want to display RSI number currently running on below code -

```
//{RSI col
rsicol = input.bool(false, title='Show RSI colors?', group='Settings ॐ', tooltip='Show RSI Levels On Bars')

srcRSI = close
lenRSI = input.int(14, minval=1, title='RSI Length', group='RSI Settings')
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(srcRSI), 0), lenRSI)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(srcRSI), 0), lenRSI)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)

rsiPlot = plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#57c269)

//coloring method below
srcRSI1 = close
lenRSI1 = input.int(60, minval=1, title='Over Bought', group='RSI Settings')
srcRSI2 = close
lenRSI2 = input.int(40, minval=1, title='Over Sold', group='RSI Settings')
isup() =>
    rsi > lenRSI1
isdown() =>
    rsi < lenRSI2
barcolor(rsicol and isup() ? color.green : rsicol and isdown() ? color.red : na)  // }
```

Tried above plot code but still not showing

Answer (score 0):

To see the RSI value, you can add at the end of your code :

```
var label LabelRSI = na // define the variable for the label
label.delete(LabelRSI)  // delete the last drawn label
LabelRSI := label.new(bar_index, rsi, str.tostring(rsi)) // draw the label
```

You will get this result :
[image]

Comment: No result  came after entering above code towards the end
c

Comment: you didn't get a blue label ?

Comment: No blue label and plotting of line is not there

Comment: You should send your entire code in your question. Perhaps you have overlay=true on your configuration, perhaps you are already drawing price on big number (like 25000), them with overlay=true, your RSI is drawing in the 50 zone and you can't see it.... If you send us bits of code, you will receive bits of answer

Comment: Yes overlay is true as im using other indicators like vwap ema's pivots and script code is long. It is not enabling me to post entire code here, Is there any way to send entire code to you or here?